# STM32 HAL_UART_Transmit_IT never returns

Tags: embedded, stm32, interrupt, uart

I have created a project using cube mx and want to use the uart4 tx and rx to send and receive bytes in interrupt mode.

I have :

```c
uint8_t buffer[] = "test\r\n";

if(HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart4, (uint8_t*)buffer, strlen(buffer))!= HAL_OK)
{

}
```

The uart initialisation is

```c
static void MX_UART4_Init(void)
{
    huart4.Instance = UART4;
    huart4.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    huart4.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart4.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart4.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart4.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart4.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart4.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    huart4.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
    huart4.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart4) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
}
```

The call to Transmit never returns and just sits there.

In the msp file I have

```c
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(UART4_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(UART4_IRQn);
```

and have in the it file

```c
void UART4_IRQHandler(void)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN UART4_IRQn 0 */

    /* USER CODE END UART4_IRQn 0 */
    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart4);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN UART4_IRQn 1 */

    /* USER CODE END UART4_IRQn 1 */
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that if I step through the Transmit function it gets to the end and is about to return HAL_OK and I get this on the Console window: Info : halted: PC: 0x08002358, this gets printed a lot of times when I step over the return statement.

Comment: IT function even if it returns OK does not mean that it has finished sending.

Comment: Is the `uint8_t buffer[]` a global variable? Have you implemented `void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)` function?

Comment: Adding a delay too allow the data to be sent fixed this problem.  HAL_Delay(100);

Answer (score 2):

the problem is related to uint8_t buffer[] = "test\r\n";
the right side is char and the left side is uint8. So, you must do as follows

```
char buffer[] = "test\r\n";
if(HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart4, (char*)buffer, strlen(buffer))!= HAL_OK)
{

}
```

or you can do this (use sizeof for int8_t not strlen)

```
unit8_t buffer[] = "test\r\n";
if(HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart4, (uint8_t*)buffer, sizeof(buffer))!= HAL_OK)
{

}
```

please add "string.h" and  in the first line of you code

Answer (score 1):

Adding a delay too allow the data to be sent fixed this problem. HAL_Delay(100)

Comment: Using delays makes no sense if you use DMA or interrupt transfers. The idea is:  the  transmission to be done in the background. If you add the delay it is better to poll instead. Delays indicate serious algorithm problems as well - and are a very bad programming habit.